# How to make a server side world time clock in xPages

Tags: datetime, timezone, xpages, serverside-javascript

I want to display to users the time in different cities/timezones like this:

London 2012-02-01 11:30:00 GMT (0)

New York 2012-02-01 06:30:00 GMT (-6)

Stockholm 2012-02-01 12:30:00 GMT (+1)

I need it to be in ssjs and generic so that it does not matter which time zone the server is in.

I have been playing around with the following code lines but can not get it to work

```
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today");
dt.setNow()

//dt.convertToZone(-6,true)
//return dt.getGMTTime()
//return dt.getZoneTime()
```

GMT is ok, but users timezone is ok as well like GMT,UTC etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would stay away from the NotesDateTime object and use the Java Date object instead. You could do something like:

```
var d:java.util.Date = new java.util.Date();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

print(dateFormat.format(d));

dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
print(dateFormat.format(d));

dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
print(dateFormat.format(d));
```

Remember that changing a timezone for a Java Date doesn't change the date itself, it just changes how it is displayed.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this worked, thanks: var d:java.util.Date = new java.util.Date();
var jdt:java.text.DateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var tz = java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");

jdt.setTimeZone(tz)
return jdt.format(d)